# Showing that 49¢ is not makeable using the given conditions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, well-orders

While going through 6.042J from MITOCW, in the text *Mathematics for Computer Science*, I came across the following problem at which I'm stuck. [image]

Now, I proceeded doing the proof in the following manner.
Suppose $C$ be the set of counterexamples to $P(n)$ where

$$P(n)::=\text{It is possible to make a postage stamp of n}¢$$
So, $$C = \bigg\{n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq50 \mid \text{P(n) is false} \bigg\}$$ where $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of non-negative integers (i.e., integers $\geq 0$)

We assume that $C$ has a least element $m \in C \text{ such that P(m) doesn't hold}$.

Assuming that $\text{51¢, 52¢, 53¢, ..., 56¢}$ are all makeable (given in the question), we can say that $$m > 56$$
$$\implies m-6 > 50$$

Now, as $\text{m is the least element in C, P(m$-6$) has to be true}$

So, $(m-6)¢$ is makeable. Thus, adding $6¢$ to it, $(m-6)¢+6¢$ is also makeable, and thus $m¢$ is also makeable.

Thus we arrive at a contradiction, i.e., $\text{P(m) is actually true}$. So, $C$ must be empty. Thus it is possible to make any amount of postage over $50¢$.

Is this proof complete and correct? Why did they say to assume that all denominations from $51¢ \text{ to } 100¢ $ were makeable, when in fact, assuming upto $56¢$ would suffice?

Also, for part $\text{(b)}$, isn't $49¢$ actually makeable? Because $49¢ = 14¢+14¢+21¢$
So why does it say to prove that it is not? Is this part incorrect?

Comment: the proof of part (a) looks pretty reasonable, though I did not scrutinize each detail. To answer your first question, the author does not say you need to assume each value from $51$ to $100$ is makeable. Rather, the author says that you may assume as many value from $51$ to $100$ as you'd like are makeable. The author then mentions that you must write down which you assumed are makeable, in your case $51,...56$.

To answer your second question, it does seem that $49$ is makable, if we take makeable to mean it is the sum of previously made values. This seems like a reasonable assumption.

Comment: @IsAdisplayName But is there any case where I'd need to assume that $57¢, ..., 100¢$ is makeable to do the proof?

Comment: It looks to me like $43$ cents is the greatest non-makeable amount.

Comment: Saying that you should only assume 51 to 56 is "makeable" would be (1) a hint at the proof and (2) not representative of studying theorems "in the wild", where we generally make many more assumptions than are necessary and only afterwards pare down the proof and recognize a smaller set of assumptions.  If I were to guess, both of those are why they didn't just tell you to assume only 51 to 56 are "makeable".

Comment: @Techie5879 Brian Moehring gives a good pedagogical reason why they introduce the problem this way. 

There are probably variants on this problem that do require assuming different values are makable. Notice that you could stop your assumptions at $56$ because you have that $6$ is makable. So if $6$ was not makable, you would need different assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of explaining the problem composers intent, on the first part of the problem is that

Since $50$ is makeable, and since the range $51$ through $100$ is makeable, you have an immediate proof by induction.

That is, assuming that the range $(50k + 1)$ through $(50k + 50)$ is makeable, and that $(50)$ is also makeable, you immediately conclude that
the range $(50[k+1] + 1)$ through $(50[k+1] + 50)$ is also makeable.

So, the problem composer is trying to stretch the intuition of the Math student into visualizing the induction principle, applied in as simple a way as possible.

As you indicated, you can conclude that since $51$ through $56$ is  makeable, and $6$ is makeable,  then an alternative approach is feasible.  The problem composer is attempting to coerce you into following the specific induction path, that he has laid out.

---

As you indicated, $(49)$ is makeable, so this is a clear mistake on the part of the problem composer.  As it turns out, each of $44$ through $48$ is also makeable.  So, the problem composer, having overreached, should have settled for asking you to show that $43$ is not makeable.

Let $a,b,c$ denote the non-negative integer scalars to be applied to $6, 14,$ and $21$, respectively.

If $c = 2$, clearly $(43- [2 \times 21])$ will not be makeable.

Suppose that $c = 1$.

Then, you have to find scalars $a,b$ so that $6a + 14b = (43 - 21) = 22.$
Neither $b = 0$, nor $b = 1$ will work in this situation.

Suppose that $c = 0$.

Then, you have to find scalars $a,b$ so that $6a + 14b = (43).$
This is impossible because $(43)$ is odd, while $6$ and $14$ are even.

Therefore, there is no satisfying combination that has $c \in \{0,1,2\}$

Therefore, $(43)$ is not makeable.